# Intercept sent notifications from an Electron app

Tags: node.js, macos, notifications, electron

Given a 3rd-party Electron app (in my case WhatsApp.app for OSX) I'd like to intercept it's calls to Notification Center as well as calls made to update it's badge. (Specifically I want this so I can display the "unread count" in the system menu bar, using TextBar).

There's an `app.asar` archive under `Resources/`, and I can see it uses a specific node module for notifications.

Before I dig further, assuming I find what I want to change, what's the way to go about intercepting those calls later? (Complete Electron newbie).

Comment: You'd have to modify the application's app.asar contents to modify its behavior. Otherwise you'd have to intercept them the same way you would with any other application (if even possible).

Comment: Thanks @AlienHoboken. I was hoping there might be a mechanism already in the Electron filesystem interface / asar loader, something like "look first in the current directory and only then, if not found, in the asar". That way I would just place a file near the asar. Or an environment variable akin to `LD_PRELOAD` but for the Electron framework?