# OSX - How can I read an app's badge from another process?

Tags: macos

In OSX, apps can have badges, typically used to show how many notifications they have. From another process, I would like to read the badge of an app. I do not have control over the app itself. How can reading the badge be done?

[image: Badge in slack]

For a little more context: I'm building a touchbar widget for OSX Mojave that displays an icon on the touchbar when there are unread messages in slack. The reason why I don't want to use the slack API is network overhead: the Slack app already handles that networking, and so I don't want to waste bandwidth with extra requests. I'd rather have a general method, but if there's a slack-specific solution that's okay. Answers in any language are acceptable.

[Intercept sent notifications from an Electron app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45005973/intercept-sent-notifications-from-an-electron-app) is related, but asks about intercepting notifications rather than querying badges directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use AppKit APIs. A working solution was found here: https://github.com/pock/pock/blob/9ee414fc35abe933057c87fab082bb9e67f5a34c/Pock/Private/PockDockHelper/PockDockHelper.m

At a high level, you create a copy of the dock as an `AXUIElementRef`, using `AXUIElementCreateApplication`. This requires the app to be authorized on the accessibility settings. From there, you can use `AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue` with `kAXStatusLabelAttribute` to read the badge.